# How to handle exception in grape (rails), if database connection is null or access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I want to handle exception while writing API in rails using Grape gem.
if database connection has been null or username or password are wrong then  it has through error.
but i want to handle it using exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you really need here but if your need is to have a central point where you can handle all exceptions of a specific type, you can use the **rescue_from** block.

```
class YourAPI::API < Grape::API

  rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
    error!(e, 400)
  end

  rescue_from YouExceptionHere do |e|
     # Do whatever you want here.
  end
end
```

If it's not what you're looking for, let me know.